# ‘Downton Abbey’

Tags: meaning-in-context

The passage below is from The Book at War by Andrew Pettegree.

> The result was not the bitter-sweet semi-autographical war trilogy
> that cemented his literary reputation, Sword of Honour, published
> between 1952 and 1961, but Brideshead Revisited, Waugh’s lyrical
> salute to a pre-war world of country houses, Oxford and Catholicism
> that continues to hold its place in the affections of readers in the
> English-speaking world. In Clement Attlee’s austerity Britain, it was
> a runaway success as it was in a United States not yet introduced to
> **Downton Abbey**. It swiftly sold half a million copies.

I want to ask what the boldfaced phrase means.
When I researched ‘Downton Abbey’, Google results show me it’s a TV drama dated 2010. Since the passage deals with the Second World War my research failed.

Can you tell me what ‘Downton Abbey’ is in this context?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is a question better suited to another website; it is about history / entertainment, not about English language  usage.

Comment: The writer is making a joke about the popularity of Downton Abbey and its relationship to Brideshead Revisited.

Comment: You're missing that Andrew Pettegree wrote his book in 2023.

Comment: Research should be more than that; e.g., see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brideshead_Revisited. It was country and cool (English noble country; US BOTM, Jan. 1946) well before English noble country was really, really cool in America (~2011) due to Downton Abbey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the TV drama started in 2010, it obviously wasn't yet available to American (or any) audiences in the 1940s!

The point is that *Downton Abbey* is about life in a great British country house. *Brideshead Revisited* also features an aristocratic family who befriend the protagonist after he meets the younger son at university.